# Execute Immediate

Tags: oracle11g

Can any one help me to to find out the error.

```
create or replace procedure sample
is
begin
  DECLARE AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COLUMNS FROM COLUMN_NAMES' INTO AGG_COLUMNS;
      END;
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE      
      'CREATE TABLE NEW_BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN AS
      (
          SELECT *
          FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN
          PIVOT
          (
            MAX(STRING_VALUE)
            FOR COLUMN_NAME IN ('||AGG_COLUMNS||')))';
  END;
end;

Error(9,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Error(17,36): PLS-00201: identifier 'AGG_COLUMNS' must be declared
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The immediate error is that the local variable `AGG_COLUMNS` is declared in the first nested PL/SQL block.  That means that it is out of scope as soon as the first nested block completes.  You cannot, therefore, use it in the second nested PL/SQL block.  You can fix that by declaring the local variable in your procedure's declaration section.  You can also get rid of the nested PL/SQL blocks

```
create or replace procedure sample
is
  AGG_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COLUMNS FROM COLUMN_NAMES' INTO AGG_COLUMNS;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE      
      'CREATE TABLE NEW_BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN AS
      (
          SELECT *
          FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN
          PIVOT
          (
            MAX(STRING_VALUE)
            FOR COLUMN_NAME IN ('||AGG_COLUMNS||')))';
end;
```

This should remove the immediate compilation error.  I'm not sure, though, whether that resolves all your problems.

- `COLUMN_NAMES` isn't a table in a default Oracle install.  This would have to be something that you created in order for this code to run.
- If you did create the `COLUMN_NAMES` table and `COLUMNS` stores a comma-separated string, then there is no need to use dynamic SQL to query the table.  You can do a simple `SELECT ... INTO`.

Comment: Justin Cave... Thank you... I resolved one error by defining a variable in declaration section. But now i have error like                                 non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values.... can u plz help me..